# How to add a loading gif to this popup, then remove it?

Tags: jquery, css, loading, animated-gif

These are really basic questions. I am tired of waiting for my website designer to fix this. It can't be that hard... I got this far by reading related questions, but I need help getting this last part done.

I want to display a loading gif in the center of the pop-up.

I want to use a gif similar to http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/29.gif but with a background that will match the message-pop-up CSS shown below (semi-transparent black).

I want the gif to be centered in the pop-up.

Most importantly, I want to remove the loading gif and display a "finished" text message after the slow function completes.

I believe the code below is enough, but if not, I will edit the question to add more info.

CSS:

```
.message-pop-up{position: fixed;width: 60%; top: 10%; height: 80%; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); color: #fff; z-index: 9999; margin: 0 auto; left: 0; right: 0;display: none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.form1').submit(function(event) {
  $('.message-pop-up').show();
  $('.popup-text').html("Just a moment please...");
  //show loading gif (how?)
    // ...do some stuff that takes time...
  //hide loading gif (how?)
  $('.popup-text').html("");
  $('.popup-text').append("Finished!");
});

$('.pop-close').click(function(event) {
  $('.message-pop-up').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="message-pop-up">
    <p class="pop-close">x</p>
    <p class="popup-text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want something like this ?
https://jsfiddle.net/yw01oukx/

Comment: @IsmailFarooq yes, similar to that. But I need jQuery to add and remove it as I mentioned in the question. Thanks

Comment: when you are showing popup ? i mean are you submitting a form or something else ?

Comment: Yes, as shown in my jQuery code, the pop-up is shown in response to form1.submit.

Comment: check out this link show popup when user click the form btn and then hide after submitting form like 
$('#form').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // your code 
 });
see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888761/i-want-to-pop-up-a-div-after-submit-a-form

Comment: still looking for a working answer...

Comment: hello see this working example might help u to understand https://jsfiddle.net/kge8eoeq/

Answer (score 0):

HTML -

```
<div class="message-pop-up">
    <p class="pop-close">x</p>
    <p class="popup-text"></p>
    <div class="popup-loader-img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.popup-loader-img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(' http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/29.gif ');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I have not tested this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But the part I'm having the most trouble with is the jQuery. See the comments in my code (in OP) for where I need help.